# Arithmetic operation in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, arithmetic

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[black] (0,-1) node{$N=0$} (-1,0) node{$g=0$};
\path[black] (1,-1) node{$\cdots$} (-1,1) node{$\vdots$};
\path[black] (-1,2) node{$b_q$};
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}
 \foreach \j in {0,...,5}{
  \draw (\i,\j) circle(3pt);
  \ifnum \j > 3+\i
   \fill[blue] (\i,\j) circle(2pt);
  \fi
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this case, the blue dots are those whose y-coordinate is greater then 3. When I change

```
\ifnum \j > 3+\i
```

to

```
\ifnum \j > \i+3
```

the blue dots become those whose y-coordinate is greater then the respective x-coordinate.

In both cases I'm not able to get the result I want, namely, the blue dots to be those whose y-coordinate is greater then the respective x-coordinate **plus** 3.

I have tried to enbrace the expression `\i+3` with `{}`, with `()` and even with `{()}`, but nothing worked.

Comment: At the moment your post is a fragment only. Please make a compilable document from it

Comment: I can't compile it yet, there is a `,` missing in the first `\foreach` statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing the TeX behavior with TikZ. `\ifnum` is a TeX primitive and doesn't understand addition at its argument.

Use

```
\ifnum\j>\numexpr3+\i\relax
```

to invoke explicit arithmetic or use Tikz' own `\pgfmathparse{int(\j-\i-3)}` and compare the result via `\ifnum\pgfmathresult>0` etc.